# Insert html into document

Tags: python, uno

I successfully created a Python script to create a document and output as PDF using UNO interface to LibreOffice Headless.

Now I have an HTML string I need to convert and insert into the document.

What I'm using right now is this:

```
document.Text.insertString(cursor, "<h1>Title</h1><p>Lorem ipsum...</p>" , False)
```

But of course it is written as is, I would like to convert the HTML styles to LibreOffice Writer.

Is this possible?.

Edit:

I want to get the same result as when I do

```
soffice --headless --convert-to pdf ipsum.html
```

*The file ipsum.html is just the Kitchen Sink example I copied from http://html-ipsum.com/.*

I cannot use this because I need to add a header and footer programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You have to insert text with paragraph style "header1", to be interpreted as H1

Comment: I've added an example of what I want to accomplish, also I must add I cannot replace tags or text, I would like to let LibreOffice do this task.

Comment: Inserting a paragraph style (as "<h1>") will always add a paragraph break in displaying the file in browsers I know.

So if you want to have it in-line: 
open the HTML file as text with Python (from a macro by READ/WRITE) and place your string at the right position.

Comment: It looks like my question is not clear enough. I need to convert any html file (stored in a string), not just some tags.